# Regular expression to validate string field with certain criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am wondering for Regular Expression that accepts only letters,numbers and dashes.

I will add it on my viewmodel class.I am working on [asp.net-mvc-4](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4) application.And using MVC Data Annotations.

I want to validate one string field there.With that regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex that matches only letters, numbers, and dashes:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z-]*$
```

Recommend you try the [gskinner regex tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), it is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If you pay attention to the above screen shot. Above is a passed case and below one is failed case.

Comment: @Pawan Please check Updates.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
/[a-zA-Z\d-]+/
```

this will validate all the alphabets, numbers and dashes.